# Tree Traversals

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I know how to write  `in-order traversal` code for `Binary Search Tree`. I just wonder, will `in-order traversal` code for **AVL Tree** and **Red-Black Tree** be same as BST code? Since all 3 has the same rules, smaller to left, larger to right, same code should work. Does anybody have any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Since AVL and Red Black Trees are self-balancing Binary Search Trees, they are still BSTs, therefore the in-order traversal code should be the same or all three of them.

Comment: how about pre-order and post-order? Will it be the same too ?

Comment: @Dosher Yes, because they have similar structure: there is a left child and right child for each node. All auxilary information which is used for balancing a tree can be ignored for a traversal.

Answer (score 1):

The `insertion`/`update`/`balancing`  process would be different for different types of tree.

But the traversal code (at least the procedure) will be almost same for all kind of tree.